# Hypergeometric Distribution not working well java

Tags: java, android, math

Im tring to calculate a probabilty using a Hypergeometric Distribution i got some help on this in the math.stackexchange but i am having problems calculating this in java

Im not an expert on this, i been tring to figure it out with no luck, i know the problem is on my java code because when i try the formula on my calculator i get the right result whitch is 0.364 in this case

This is the formula

[image]

The Binomial is calculated this way

`(K k) =   K! / ((K - k)! * k!)`

This is how im trying to replicate this in java code

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    BigDecimal[] prob = HyperGeometricDistribution(20,2,50,5);
    String _prob = prob[0] + "." +  prob[1];
    System.out.println(_prob);
}

private static BigDecimal fact(BigDecimal n) {
    BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ONE;
    while (!n.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)) {
        result = result.multiply(n);
        n = n.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);
    }
    return result;
}

private static BigDecimal Binomial(int a, int b) {
    return fact(BigDecimal.valueOf(a)).divide(fact(BigDecimal.valueOf(a-b)).multiply(fact(BigDecimal.valueOf(b))), BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
}

// K : Number of Successes in Population
// k : number of Successes in Sample
// N : Population Size
// m : Sample Size
private static BigDecimal[] HyperGeometricDistribution(int K,int k, int N, int m){
    return (Binomial(K,k).multiply(Binomial(N-K,m-k))).divideAndRemainder(Binomial(N,m));
}
```

This will print 0.77 however the correct answer is 0.364 [Online Example](https://www.geneprof.org/GeneProf/tools/hypergeometric.jsp)

I will be using this in android, the max value i will pass in **N** is 3910 i need to use BigDecimals since i need to calculate 3910! and this is a huge number.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remainder of `divideAndRemainder()` is not the fractional part of a decimal representation. You would need to divide the remainder by the actual divisor.

But actually, you do not need `BigDecimal`. You just need a smart way of calculating it. Let's check the formula for the binomial coefficient and for example `n=5, k=3`. Then:

```
c(5, 3) = (5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1) / ((2 * 1) * (3 * 2 * 1))
```

As you see, the `(n-k)!` part cancels out completely and you end up with

```
c(5, 3) = (5 * 4 * 3) / (3 * 2 * 1)
        = 5/3 * 4/2 * 3/1
```

So you just need to multiply `k` fractions. And if you always reduce the fractions, you will not need very large numbers. In fact, the calculation of the hypergeometric distribution is also a fraction, where you can reduce things again to keep the numbers small. Here is some C# code that does this. It is nothing fancy and translates almost exactly to Java:

```
static class GCDHelper
{
    public static long GCD(long a, long b)
    {
        while(b != 0)
        {
            var temp = b;
            b = a % b;
            a = temp;
        }
        return a;
    }
}

class Fraction
{
    public long Numerator;
    public long Denominator;

    public Fraction(long numerator, long denominator)
    {
        this.Numerator = numerator;
        this.Denominator = denominator;
    }

    public void Reduce()
    {
        var gcd = GCDHelper.GCD(Numerator, Denominator);
        Numerator /= gcd;
        Denominator /= gcd;
    }

    public double ToNumber() { return (double)Numerator / Denominator; }
}

class Program
{
    static void MultiplyBinomialCoefficient(int n, int k, bool inverse, Fraction f)
    {
        if (k > n / 2)
            k = n - k;
        for(int i = 1; i <= k; ++i)
        {
            if (!inverse)
            {
                f.Numerator *= n - i + 1;
                f.Denominator *= i;
            }
            else
            {
                f.Denominator *= n - i + 1;
                f.Numerator *= i;
            }
            f.Reduce();
        }
    }

    static double Hypergeometric(int K, int k, int N, int m)
    {
        var f = new Fraction(1, 1);
        MultiplyBinomialCoefficient(K, k, false, f);
        MultiplyBinomialCoefficient(N - K, m - k, false, f);
        MultiplyBinomialCoefficient(N, m, true, f);
        return f.ToNumber();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Hypergeometric(20, 2, 50, 5));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
0.364080877494384
```

There are still a few parameter combinations that let the numbers overflow. Luckily, you can just replace the `long` variables with `BigInteger` ones (and adjust the operators accordingly). The rest should then work just fine.

Comment: I had to replace the `long` with `BigInteger`, because i was having problems with big numbers, but everything works now thanks a lot